# How fast should I make a human detector signal?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, dynamical-systems

So I am designing a break beam and I want to be able to catch all people running at whatever speed they can possibly run at.. I need to pulse the signal (ideally between 1-50Hz.. after 50Hz my sensors range sucks)

But I am getting myself confused with the math..

If we say the top speed of a human is 50km/h and I want my beams 10cm apart..

or even just 1 beam..

So 50km/h is 1388.88889 cm/s
and the max speed of my sensor is 50Hz = 0.02s

If the average person is what.. 30cm wide?

Argh confused, I swear I am nearly there.. basically is 50Hz fast enough to detect someone..

Comment: At $50$ km/h an object moves by $27.\overline 7$ cm in $\frac1{50}$ s, so if it is at leats $30$ cm thick, it cannot slip through the pulse gap.

Comment: Thank you so much..  I was getting so muddled up